# matlab function "m = size(X,dim)" equivalent in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to Matlab, can anyone help me to find the equivalent opencv method for the matlab method "m = size(X,dim)"". It would also be better if i get to know what it does? The online documents are not helpful for my little knowledge. Thanks

Update:

What is the role of Dim "m = size(X,dim)" and how it works. For the image(x) size of 200 * 200 , if i pass dim=1, i get m=1 in matlab and if i pass dim =2 , then i get 40. Can you pl explain.

Code:

```
image = 'D:\Proposals\others\test_some_title1.jpg'
top=size(image,2)
```

Comment: May i know why my question got down voted? I have gone through the stuff available in the internet, but couldn't understand. As its a simple one line method, i am not sure how to ask this question in a better way. Asking question in stack overflow doesn't show i am not putting effort from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your code:

```
image = 'D:\Proposals\others\test_some_title1.jpg'
top=size(image,2)
```

`image` here is not an image.  It is a string containing a file name (which happens to be an image, but the `size` function doesn't know that). The string is indeed 40 characters long, hence the result. To actually read in an image, use `imread`.

Also, `image` itself is a function in MATLAB.  If you make a variable called `image` it will stop you using the function properly (this is the source of a lot of MATLAB errors).

Answer (score 3):

Your title pretty much answers how to access the dimension.  You use the `size` command.  I'm not even sure why this question was even asked.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html.  Doing a Google search, this was the first link that came up.

### Referring to your code

You did not read in the image properly.  You are checking the size **of the string** that contains the filename.  You didn't read in the image itself.  Call `imread` first via:

```
im = imread('D:\Proposals\others\test_some_title1.jpg');
```

Now do:

```
top = size(im, 2);
```

The reason why you get a `1 x 40` size is because your filename string is 40 characters long.

Also, referring to what @nkjt said, you should not shadow over the `image` command with a variable called `image`.  `image` is used to take a matrix and display it on the screen as an image.  Bear in mind this is not the same as `imshow`.  Suggest you change the variable name to something like `im` like what I did.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the role of Dim "m = size(X,dim)" and how it works. For the image(x) size of 200 * 200 , if i pass dim=1, i get m=1 in matlab and if i pass dim =2 , then i get 40. Can you pl explain

Comment: That probably means you're passing the wrong variable to size :) Can we see some code?

Comment: You are right, i have seen this link, but the problem is, i am not able to understand it with my knowledge. Thats the reason i posted this question.

Comment: Edit your post so we can see some code.  My suspicion is that you're not passing the right variable to `size`.

Answer (score -1):

I got your point. Because this function "m = size(X,dim)" finds the size of each dimension of your matrix X, you get answer 1 when you input dim = 1, and 40 when you input dim = 2.

your input message 'D:\Proposals\others\test_some_title1.jpg' is read as a matrix. It has one row and 40 columns. So dimension of X will be 1x40.

To answer your question, what I understood is the matrix X now has dimension 1x40. one row and 40 columns. if you want to know the size of first dimension, you type m = size(X,1). You will get m = 1. For the second dimension which is 40, you type m= size(X,2), you will get 40. Because this matrix X has only two dimension, if you type a number greater than 2, matlab will return default value 1. You don't care about that!